# Rendering controller to a different view in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Is there a way to render a controller to a different view then normal? I'm trying to pass some data from the controller to a non-default view. Meaning my controller is called:

```
class StocksRealtimeController extends AppController {
    var $uses               = 'StockRealtime';
    function index(){
        $action = '/TestView';
        $this->set('stocksRT', $this->StockRealtime->find('all'));
        //$this -> viewPath = 'Pages';
        $this -> render('/TestView/index');
    }
}
```

... and My view is in views->TestView->index.ctp

Another question I have is, how to pass that value to a PHP and not a ctp file outside of the CakePHP framework?

I have tried everything from [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/980/render) with no luck.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The right way:

`$this -> render('TestView/index');`

As the answer above mentions, you can use `$this -> set` to pass a variable to the View.

However, if that doesn't give you what you want. I'm guessing that you also want the action to display another layout (non-default layout). You can try doing `$this -> layout = 'layoutname';` (Layouts are in the layout folder, default on is default.ctp).

**Note:** CakePHP's controller isn't designed to pass data to a non-view file (like .php). CakePHP's views should be ending with `.ctp`.

Comment: maybe I'm late.. but if you set variable "*_for_layout" will be available in layout too.

Comment: For me, I needed to put a / in front of the path (e.g. `/TestView/index`).

Comment: A warning. Calling `$this->render()` before viewVars are set will make them unavailable in your view.

Comment: The `render()` method will stop the controller execution and whatever code is after that line will be omitted. Setting the `view` property instead is a better idea, the answer from @Sabin Neagu should be accepted.

Comment: As of date, [Cake v2.x](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::render) and [Cake v3.x](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#Cake\Controller\Controller::render) will need a leading `/` if you want to render a view from within `/app/View` and no leading `/` if the view to be rendered is from a plugin. Linked to appropriate documentation.

Comment: @KevinJurkowski Forward slah  `"/"` is what i am looking for .! Thanks man :)

Answer (score 47):

I would rather use:

```
$this->view = 'file';
```

because any `$this->set('var', $val)` you'll have after `$this->render('file')` will not reach your view.

In CakePHP 3.x use:

```
$this->viewBuilder()->template('file');
```

Deprecated in CakePHP 3.7.
Use this instead (as Kuldeep Choudhary suggested in comments)

```
ViewBuilder::setTemplate('file');
```

Comment: No wonder! I was so sure I was setting the variable correctly, but the view pops a notice that 'it' is not set. Thanks for that tip!

Comment: This should be the recommended answer; it fits best with the cake paradigm.

Comment: Agreed, looks more flexible to me. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Now in CakePHP 3.7 - $this->viewBuilder()->setTemplate('file'); -

Warning (512): ViewBuilder::template() is deprecated. Use ViewBuilder::setTemplate() or ViewBuilder::getTemplate() instead

Answer (score 11):

Try to put the name of the view without .ctp extension.

```
$this->render('file');
```

Comment: that's what I did in the example.

Answer (score 3):

```
class StocksRealtimeController extends AppController
{
   var $uses = 'StockRealtime';

   function index( )
   {
     $this->layout     = NULL;
     $this->autoRender = false;

     $this->set('stocksRT', $this->StockRealtime->find('all'));

     return $this -> render('/TestView/index');
     /*
        $this -> render('/TestView/index');
        Here 'TestView' must be a Folder named same as "public $name" variable value        
        in Controller and an "index.ctp" must be situated under TestView Folder.
       'index'
     */
   }
}
```

Give it a try, return 'KEYWORD' must be there to render view page successfully.
Sorry about 2nd question as i didn't get it.
According to CakePHP, variable [stocksTR] which is set using
$this -> set( ) , also will be available at manually render view page [ 'index.ctp' ].

Answer (score 1):

```
 $this->view  = '/TestView/index';
 $this->set('stocksRT', $this->StockRealtime->find('all'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class StocksRealtimeController extends AppController {
var $uses               = 'StockRealtime';

    function index(){

       $this->layout = NULL;
       $this->autoRender = false;

       $this->set('stocksRT', $this->StockRealtime->find('all'));

       $this -> render(`/TestView/index`);

    }
}
```

Comment: I did what you suggested , and still, the page http://localhost/cakephp/TestView,  looks for the testcontroller => "Error: TestViewController could not be found."

Answer (score 0):

```
public function admin_index() { 

    $this->layout = 'admin/table';

    $action = '/Vendors';

    $this->Prg->commonProcess('Vendor');

    $this->paginate = array('conditions' => array($this->Vendor->parseCriteria($this->passedArgs)), 'order' => 'Vendor.created_on DESC', 'limit' => 15);

    $this->set('vendor', $this->paginate('Vendor'));

    $this->render('/vendors/admin_items');
}
```