# CakePhp help needed

Tags: cakephp

I am a newbie to cakephp. For security updation I am asking the user to enter his date of birth. If he enters the correct date of birth i want to show him the other form which contains his security question and then his password.

There are two different forms.One is security check(date of birth verification) and the other is set security(security question + password).

If the security is set then security check form is first shown and asks to enter his date of birth.If date of birth is correct then set security form should be shown,which i am unable to do.

My profile page code which shows these two forms;

```
<?php if($_GET['edit'] == 'set_security'){ ?>
        <?php if (empty($security_set)): ?>
        <?= $this->element('../users/set_security') ?>
        <?php else:?>
         <?= $this->element('../users/set_security_check') ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

The function which I have written in conntroller is,

```
function set_security_check()
{
   $user = $this->_authenticate_user();
   $id = $user['account_num'];
   $this->loadModel('UserProfile');
   $user_profile = $this->UserProfile->read(null, $id);
   $oldBirthdate = $user_profile['UserProfile']['birthday']; 
     if (!empty($this->data)) {
         $birthday = $this->data['UserProfile']['birthday'];
         if($oldBirthdate != $birthday)
         {
           $this->flashMessage(__('Your Birthday is Invalid. Please, try again.', true));

         }
         else
         {
          $this->flashMessage(__('Your Birthday Verified successfully', true), 'Sucmessage');
          $this->set('success', true);
         }

     }


}
```

When user click on security edit buttons I am sending a query string /profile?edit=set_security.

How to show the other form when correct date of birth is entered?

Comment: What is $security_set in your view file, means what it contains?

Comment: thank you sir for your reply.$security_set means if the user has already set his security.Meaning he has filled the security form and entered his security question.I he had set his security and wants to update it.then if he click on edit,first he is shown his date of birth.If he enters correct date of birth then he is shown the other form.The other form I can not show him?

Comment: Better question title needed urgent. Are you really asking how to render a different view file? Your code in general looks quite odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply show any other form using the following code in your controller where your conditions meets:

```
$this->render('/users/other_form');
```

If I am correct, then your code should looks like:

```
function set_security_check()
{
  $user = $this->_authenticate_user();
  $id = $user['account_num'];
  $this->loadModel('UserProfile');
  $user_profile = $this->UserProfile->read(null, $id);
  $oldBirthdate = $user_profile['UserProfile']['birthday']; 
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
     $birthday = $this->data['UserProfile']['birthday'];
     if($oldBirthdate != $birthday)
     {
       $this->flashMessage(__('Your Birthday is Invalid. Please, try again.', true));

     }
     else
     {
      $this->flashMessage(__('Your Birthday Verified successfully', true), 'Sucmessage');
      $this->set('success', true);
      $this->render('/controller_name/other_form');
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: This link might help you to achieve the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11711385/rendering-controller-to-a-different-view-in-cakephp